# pr2 (gazebo simulator) gripper not strong enough

Tags: ros, gazebo, pr2-tabletop-manipulation-apps, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using ros-diamondback and gazebo for pr2_simulator.

My problem is that if I do

roslaunch pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch
rosrun pr2_pick_and_place_demos pick_and_place_demo.py

the gripper is not strong enough to hold on to the graspable object, and it drops the object before it finshes the task.

When I was using Fuerte before, I didn't have this problem.

Can someone teach me how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37557/pr2-(gazebo-simulator)-gripper-not-strong-enough/) by [joey0702](https://answers.ros.org/users/2681/joey0702/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps this is a related question and hope you can find out something here. http://answers.ros.org/question/33566/pr2-keeps-dropping-objects/

---

Originally posted by [Nan Jiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/2653/nan-jiang/) with karma: 131 on 2012-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0